# Unable to execute Doug Crockford's deentityify example in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute that really nice deentityify example in Douglas Crockfords J-TBP book using jsfiddle

```
String.method('deentityify', function() {
    // The entity table. It maps entity names to
    // characters.
    var entity = {
        quot: '"',
        lt: '<',
        gt: '>'
    };
    // Return the deentityify method.
    return function() {
        // This is the deentityify method. It calls the string
        // replace method, looking for substrings that start
        // with '&' and end with ';'. If the characters in
        // between are in the entity table, then replace the
        // entity with the character from the table. It uses
        // a regular expression (Chapter 7).
        return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g, function(a, b) {
            var r = entity[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
        });
    };
}());

document.writeln('&lt;&quot;&gt;'.deentityify()); // <">
```

- see http://jsfiddle.net/cspeter8/7Pjzs/2/ - and it does not work!  I would expect the results pane to display '<">' but nothing shows up.  Would someone like to solve the mystery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code-snippet depends on a bit of sugar, namely the `method` method, that you have to define beforehand. (It's described early on in the book.) An online copy and explanation of it are in [the "Sugar" section of Crockford's article "Classical Inheritance in JavaScript"](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html#sugar). It looks like this:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

A corrected version of your Fiddle, incorporating the above, is at http://jsfiddle.net/W9Ncd/.